# Why has Allah used plural pronouns for Himself?

Tags: tafseer, allah

When the Almighty Allah is One, unique and peerless, and knows about His oneness, then why in the Holy Quran he uses the plural pronoun (We) for Himself?

Comment: I did not understand you please add some example.

Answer (score 4):

In the Arabic, Farsi and Urdu language the plural nouns are normally used to denote respect.

When Allah talks about Himself, His names, His attributes(siffat), His essence; He talks about these things with a language of respect, using the plurals.

This is just how language is. And when this is translated into the English language the term "We" or "Us" is used.